# Java Multithreading : changing variable from multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Say I have class

```
public class OuterClass
{
    public static WorkerClass worker;
}
```

In thread 1

The following command is executed

```
Outerclass.worker.doLongRunningOperation();
```

while the `doLongRunningOperation` is executed, in thread 2

```
Outerclass.worker = new WokerClass();
```

What will happen to the `doLongRunningOperation` in thread 1?

Will the `worker` Object referenced by thread 1 be garbage collected, only after the `doLongRunningOperation` is complete or can it be abruptly terminated to garbage collect `worker` Object.

Edit :

I think it should be GC'ed, since it is no longer referenced. But what will happen to the `doLongRunningOperation`? will it be terminated abruptly?

Comment: Can you clarify what you think will happen and why? What are some reasons why it should be GC'ed and what are some reasons it shouldn't?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have clarified it in edit.

Comment: You mentioned _after the `doLongRunningOperation` is complete_ so I'm confused by your new question _will it be terminated abruptly?_ Look into the concept of GC roots.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis sorry, my bad, I have clarified that part. English is not my first language.

Comment: If (and while) a thread is invoking an instance method, it obviously needs a reference to that instance. If there's such a reachable reference to an instance, that instance cannot be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java garbage collector (GC) reclaims objects that are not *traceable* starting from a set of GC *roots*.  That is, if object A is referenced by object B, and object B is referenced by object C, and object C is referenced by a *root*, then objects A, B, and C are all safe from the garbage collector.

So what are the roots?  I don't know the complete answer, but I do know that the root set includes every local variable and parameter in every running thread.

So, if some local variable or argument in thread 1 still has a reference to the original `WorkerClass` instance, then the instance will continue to live.

The original WorkerClass instance will only be reclaimed when it is not referenced by any local or arg in *any* thread or, by any field in any traceable object.  When that happens, it won't matter to your program any more because your program will no longer have any means to access the object.

---

P.S., "arguments and locals" includes *hidden* variables that are part of the Java implementation, and it includes *implicit* variable such as the `this` reference in every object method.  Your original `WorkerClass` instance can not be reclaimed as long any method call on it (e.g., `doLongRunningOperation`) still is active.